# Append rows from pandas df to a new csv while preserving the headers once?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, loops, export-to-csv

My goal is to open a very large csv file, read the file, then do stuff on the subset of data. In this case, "stuff" is writing to a blank csv, but in future it will be running functions on the data, 200 rows at a time (this saves computing time on my end for some reason, over running the entire csv through the functions).

My current problem is that when I write a blank csv, if I use `header = False`, I have no headers, but if I take out that command, I have the header every 200 rows. I want the header once at the top if this is possible?

```
with open(csvFile, encoding = 'utf8', errors = 'ignore') as csv_file:
chunksize = 200
i = 0
j = 1
for df in pd.read_csv(csv_file, encoding = 'utf-8', chunksize=chunksize, iterator=True):
      df.index += j
      i+=1
      df.to_csv('test.csv', mode = 'a', sep = ',', encoding='utf-8', header=False, index=False)
      j = df.index[-1] + 1
```

Comment: `for df in pd.read_csv` is super-confusing syntax btw because it's not a `df` at all. That name is, for all intents and purposes, reserved for `pandas.DataFrame()`.

Comment: Secondly it's completely possible, from my understanding of the question, but we're missing detail on what the code actually does

Comment: No, actually, my comments don't make sense, but neither does "(this saves computing time on my end for some reason, over running the entire csv through the functions)". I'll leave my (incorrect) comments for now because that's the avenue your question sent my thoughts down, but that statement hints at a broader issue IMO. There's no way I can see that processing the file in chunks like that and appending back out is faster, unless you're thrashing memory on a CSV that won't fit into memory

Comment: @roganjosh, notice the `iterator=True` within the `read_csv`. That causes `read_csv` to return an iterator than when looped via a for loop, will return individual dataframes (df).

Comment: @Kyle Please see my last comment after I've edited it. If you see what I'm missing, please do add to an answer and I will upvote

Comment: Its hard to say, depends on the complexity of the functions and if they are effectively vectorized or not. I have run into cases where chunking was useful, but generally on the order of >50,000 rows at a time.

Answer (score 2):

Just put `header=True` in the first time you write.

```
with open(csvFile, encoding = 'utf8', errors = 'ignore') as csv_file:
    chunksize = 200
    i = 0
    j = 1
    for df in pd.read_csv(csv_file, encoding = 'utf-8', chunksize=chunksize, iterator=True):
        df.index += j
        i += 1
        if i == 1:
            df.to_csv('test.csv', mode = 'w', sep = ',', encoding='utf-8', header=True, index=False)
        else:
            df.to_csv('test.csv', mode = 'a', sep = ',', encoding='utf-8', header=False, index=False)
        j = df.index[-1] + 1
```

Comment: `df.to_csv('test.csv', mode = 'w', sep = ',', encoding='utf-8', header=i==1, index=False)`, and you can wrap the read_csv in an `enumerate` to get rid of the other lines.

Answer (score 1):

You could `import os` and use, I have not written all your code, but the main basis is

```py
if os.path.exists(csv_file):
    headers=false
else:
    headers=true
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a CSV file and insert the header you want. For example:

```
some,kind,of,header,content
```

Later when you will insert your dataframe you will not need to make a header by code.